# Get index in array if string exists in it using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, contains

I'm using this code to check if the string (oCode/ originalCode) exists in the array (the string is written by user):

```
if (dic.cs.Any(code.Contains)) //dic.cs is in another class (cs is the array), the code variable is what I look for in the array
{
   //I want to get the string was found in the array with the "Contains" function
}
```

I want to get the string that was found in the array with the `Contains()` function.

Comment: Use `IndexOf` method.

Comment: What is the code variable? Could you give us a little more context as to what's going on here? But, I did take a stab at answering below.

Comment: True, i will edit... the code variable is the string I want to search the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to have multiple matches, then use this:

```
var foundCodes = dic.cs.Where(code.Contains);
foreach(var foundCode in foundCodes)
{

}
```

Otherwise:

```
var foundCode = dic.cs.FirstOrDefault(code.Contains);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(foundCode))
{ 

}
```

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty() would probably be safer than just checking for null. This is how I would solve this though. Good answer.

Comment: His question said he wants the index. Neither solution gives an index.

Comment: @dman2306 "I want to get the string that was found in the array". Where is the mention of the index?

Comment: @rob the title "get index in array of string exists in  it using c#"

Comment: @dman2306 Fair enough - but the body of the question contradicts the title in that case

Answer (score 0):

You need a lambda expression in the Any method:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Quantifiers-f00e7e3e#AnySimple

```
var answer = yourArray.any(a => a == "WhatYouAreLookingFor");
```

if answer is true, then you found it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is the array IndexOf method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx